# In geom_bar, hide one bar but account for it in total calculations

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset, percentage

I am just doing a bar plot with `ggplot2`. I want to hide one of the bars, but still consider it for the % calculations. See my MWE below.

For this example  I am using the `mtcars` data.

This is what I do:

```
data(mtcars)
P <- ggplot2::ggplot(mtcars, ggplot2::aes(as.character(carb))) +
  ggplot2::geom_bar(position="identity", stat="count") +
  ggplot2::geom_text(stat='count', ggplot2::aes(label=
    paste0(round((ggplot2::after_stat(count))/sum(ggplot2::after_stat(count)),2)*100,'%')), vjust=-1) +
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(name="carb") +
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(name="number cars") +
  ggplot2::theme_light()
grDevices::pdf(file="test.pdf", height=8, width=10)
print(P)
grDevices::dev.off()
```

Which produces this:

[image: test]

As you can see, I am trying to measure the number of cars with each `carb` value. Additionally, I am indicating the % of cars for each `carb` value over the total number of cars. All good.

However, in my real data, the value for `1` is much higher than any other (making the other bars look flat).

I want to remove the `1` bar from the plot, but if I just do `subset(mtcars, carb>1)`, the % is calculated over the subset, and I want to keep the original % values including `carb==1`.

How should I go about this? Only way I can think of is to calculate the % outside of `ggplot2` and then use that variable instead inside `geom_text`, but I am wondering whether some option exists to "hide" some x value.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Expected result should be like the image below; my intention is more to remove specific x values, not pass a y limit.

[image: test2]

Comment: Do you want to remove the carb = 1 value on the x axis or just have the carb = 1 break empty, i.e. just remove the bar and text above?

Comment: I want to remove the whole bar for carb=1 altogether, while preserving the same % values as in the plot above (essentially, exactly the plot above but without the first bar) - this means the %s in the final plot should not add up to 100%, but 100-22=78%

Answer (score 0):

you can limit the y-axis *without* excluding excess data from the stats with:

```
## ggplot stuff +
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, your_limit_here))
```

{[ggbreak](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggbreak/vignettes/ggbreak.html)} offers utilities for axis with gaps

Comment: This does not work as expected... I add `ggplot2::coord_cartesian(xlim = c(2, max(mtcars$carb)))` but the plot looks very off and the % is still calculated as if I removed the 1 values altogether

Comment: Also I don't want to add gaps in a plot, and for my purposes I don't need to visualize the `1` (it's count data and I am looking at entries shared across samples, so do not care about the 1 - but I still want to know the % over the global data, including the 1)

Comment: You need to set `ylim`, not `xlim` to affect the vertical axis.

Comment: is there no way to pass the x limit to remove the `1` explicitly?

Comment: how do I calculate `your_limit_here`? I do not know that value a priori, that is the whole point why I make this plots

Comment: plus... in the MWE in particular, this approach would also remove bars for `2` and `4`...